# Column selection in TextWrangler with keyboard only

Tags: textwrangler

I am aware that I can select a column (or block, or rectangle) of text in TextWrangler with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+mouse drag or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ mouse click. Both of these actions require the use of mouse. I'd like to know if it's possible to do this with keyboard only.

Comment: Great tips! - This is actually the first result from Google searching how to select block text in textwrangler :)

Answer (score 4):

Having struggled a little with this, also looking for the key-only combinations, it appears the answer may unfortunately well be *no*. The mouse is needed.

See the [TextWrangler FAQ](http://www.barebones.com/support/textwrangler/faqs.html#rectangle).

[Their manual](http://pine.barebones.com/manual/TextWrangler_User_Manual.pdf) also only makes mention of the use of the mouse under "Rectangular Selections"

Answer (score 3):

**On MacOS**

1. With the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key held down,
2. use the left/right `arrow` to highlight some text on the current line.
3. Then, still holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key,
4. press and hold the <kbd>Control</kbd> key and use the up/down `arrow` to select the lines for rectangle.

*Note:* if your up/down gets to a line that's shorter than the left edge of your selection, strange things happen.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, pressing control + arrow key triggers an overview screen with all application's windows and recent documents lined up.

Comment: Same as shrx for me - this is on MacOS, windows may be different.

Comment: I tested again...still works.  Note: TextWrangler 5.5.2.   There's a photo at www.sieler.com/text.html which shows a block of four lines by six characters .  Critical: this only works if the initial text selection is all on the same line.  As soon as you hit up/down during that first phase, you lose your chance.

Comment: This is the right answer. Just make sure that  **“Soft Wrap Text” option is turned off**. If the combo triggers some OS-level shortcut, then that is because it is defined to do so in your system. That should be possible to change.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, I have used **Shift + alt/option**.

Place the cursor to the left of the first Character/column you want to select. Press and hold **Shift + alt** and place cursor to the right of the final character you want selected (you can scroll all the down the page but continue to hold **Shift + alt**). As long as you continue to hold down **Shift + alt**, you will be able to adjust the selected text.

This has worked for me so far.

Comment: Are you saying that this works with the cursor movement ***keys**?* If so, please ***say so*** (*in* your answer).